# Typo in tooltip on bounty on reputation tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling

As you can see in this screenshot, there's a typo in the tooltip you get for the word "bounty" on the reputation tab; the word *received* is spelled *reveiced*.

[image: Screenshot showing typo]

Comment: Inbound giant bludgeoning 's'... _ducks_

Comment: What?!? Someone who actually reads the tooltips? I don't believe it.

Comment: teh developer who wrote it is definitely a blind typist :)

Comment: @Cody - nope...which is why I didn't notice, and copied it to another view as well, total #win - fixed in the next build.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, a quick cross reference with a reputable dictionary confirms the spelling is incorrect.

Comment: Sooo tempted to edit the answer to read "recerenfe"